# Highstock date input jquery ui datepicker position changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, highcharts

In Highstock, you can use the jquery ui datepicker instead of inputting text into the date fields, as in this demo... http://jsfiddle.net/hcharge/aNde9/

```
datepicker
```

Clicking the input once, opens the datepicker where it should be below the input field, however if you close it and open it again it then sticks to the top of the container.  Implemented in a webpage this would be the top of the browser window.

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The datepicker controls its vertical position through the 'top' attribute of the widget's style - for some reason the 'top' is always set to 0 in subsequent datepicker activations.

It is relatively easy to workaround though if we have the widget's data 'remember' the correct position and explicitly set that position in the subsequent calls.
See the 'onClose' and 'beforeShow' functions defined within the datePicker options below:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {
    // Create the chart
    window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart : {
            renderTo : 'container'
        },

        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1,
            inputDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d',
            inputEditDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d'
        },

        title : {
            text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'AAPL',
            data : data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]

    }, function(chart){

        // apply the date pickers
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('input.highcharts-range-selector', $('#'+chart.options.chart.renderTo))
            .datepicker({
                beforeShow: function(i,obj) {
                    $widget = obj.dpDiv;
                    window.$uiDatepickerDiv = $widget;
                    if ($widget.data("top")) {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $uiDatepickerDiv.css( "top", $uiDatepickerDiv.data("top") );
                        },50);
                    }
                }
                ,onClose: function(i,obj) {
                    $widget = obj.dpDiv;
                    $widget.data("top", $widget.position().top);
                }
            })
        },0)
    });
});
```

Here's a [**link to jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/aNde9/12/)

Comment: yeah i think we will try and go with this, a shame it doesn't work out of the box, thanks very much

Comment: But when using multiple graphs and using multiple datapickers this solution fails. It shows the datapicker always in the same graph instead of in the one you are clicking to show the dates. See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aNde9/52/

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the same input formats, so or change in datepicker `dateFormat` to the same as in Highstock , or change `inputRangeFormat` in Highstock.

Comment: i've updated the fiddle with the formats matching but seems to have made no difference, it's a very strange bug

Comment: you have error in format `'%Y-&m-%d'` while should be `'%Y-%m-%d'`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/aNde9/4/

Comment: I realised that error and corrected it, it still doesn't work as expected though, do you see what I'm talking about? The datepicker sticks to the top of the container...

Comment: Just realized, that I wasn't answering on your question, sorry!
Yes, now I can see that position of datepicker is wrong.