# Highstock + Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, highcharts, bootstrap-datepicker

My question is the same as the one here:
[Highstock date input jquery ui datepicker position changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007182/highstock-date-input-jquery-ui-datepicker-position-changes)

But I'm using Bootstrap datepicker instead of jQuery. I noticed it has on("show", ... ), on("hide" ...) instead of beforeShow, onClose respectively. But then I don't really know how to change their bodies to work with my datepicker.

Comment: Could you replciate your example as live demo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('input.highcharts-range-selector', $(chart.container).parent())
                .datepicker({
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                todayBtn: "linked",
                orientation: "auto left",
                autoclose: true,
                todayHighlight: true
            });
        }, 0);
```