# Using Bootstrap Datepicker with Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to implement the solution here: [Highstock + Bootstrap datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24450249/highstock-bootstrap-datepicker) but I end up with an Undefined error in my console.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rlsaj/r6es2jyc/.

```
  setTimeout(function () {
        $('input.highcharts-range-selector', $(chart.container).parent())
            .datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            todayBtn: "linked",
            orientation: "auto left",
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true
        });
    }, 0);
```

My goal is to implement the Angular Bootstrap datepicker (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) but I think I can solve that if the above fiddle can be fixed.

Comment: Still no error dude. When does the error occur? And what does the error say?

Comment: damnit, I keep on sharing the wrong fiddle. Updated and the error occurs when trying to use the date picker (top right).

Comment: I added a `Jquery` resource (1.8) and changed the framework of `Jsfiddle` to `1.9.1` and the errors are gone: http://jsfiddle.net/r6es2jyc/1/ But when trying to open the datepicker, it says `Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined`. I don't know what `msie` is, do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) bootstrap requires a more recent jQuery version.

2.) bootstrap does not contain a native datepicker.  I imagine you want to use [this](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/release/docs/index.rst#id1), so you'll need to source it in:

```
<script src="http://rawgit.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/release/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

3.) `setDefaults` is a method of jquery-ui's datepicker not the bootstrap implementation I link above.

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6es2jyc/2/).